# Google API returned incorrect language content

Tags: javascript, google-admin-sdk

The request url is language=TW , however below request result GEOMETRIC_CENTER content are English not Chinese .

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.47103,113.99985&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&language=zh_TW

The result should be in Chinese wording only . Please advise and fix it.

```html
{
   "plus_code" : {
      "compound_code" : "FXCX+CW 香港",
      "global_code" : "7PJMFXCX+CW"
   },
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Tin Shui Wai",
               "short_name" : "Tin Shui Wai",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New Territories",
               "short_name" : "New Territories",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Tin Heng Estate, Tin Shui Wai, 香港",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.470815,
               "lng" : 113.9997488
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4721639802915,
                  "lng" : 114.0010977802915
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4694660197085,
                  "lng" : 113.9983998197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJZR0vw1_wAzQRDVp9T8L9tbM",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "FXCX+8V 香港",
            "global_code" : "7PJMFXCX+8V"
         },
         "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest", "school", "secondary_school" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "天瑞徑",
               "short_name" : "天瑞徑",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "元朗",
               "short_name" : "元朗",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "新界",
               "short_name" : "新界",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港元朗天瑞徑",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4721679,
                  "lng" : 113.9999795
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4663805,
                  "lng" : 113.9963565
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.4695168,
               "lng" : 113.9977616
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4721679,
                  "lng" : 113.9999795
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4663805,
                  "lng" : 113.9963565
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJASY1z1_wAzQRzvh4J77GMHI",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "天水圍",
               "short_name" : "天水圍",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "新界",
               "short_name" : "新界",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港天水圍",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4736994,
                  "lng" : 114.0133023
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4432004,
                  "lng" : 113.9932241
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.4606419,
               "lng" : 114.0041996
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4736994,
                  "lng" : 114.0133023
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4432004,
                  "lng" : 113.9932241
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJmV-RB4jwAzQRhLL8dPEpR9Y",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "元朗區",
               "short_name" : "元朗區",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "新界",
               "short_name" : "新界",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港元朗區",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.522099,
                  "lng" : 114.122832
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4049351,
                  "lng" : 113.935229
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.4445484,
               "lng" : 114.0222095
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.522099,
                  "lng" : 114.122832
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.4049351,
                  "lng" : 113.935229
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJYZRjYwrwAzQRVRY2HNSIBbo",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "新界",
               "short_name" : "新界",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港新界",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.561969,
                  "lng" : 114.441442
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.153415,
                  "lng" : 113.835078
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.3704243,
               "lng" : 114.1234149
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.561969,
                  "lng" : 114.441442
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.153415,
                  "lng" : 113.835078
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJt8ZyJegABDQRyJEH8bJo_iI",
         "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "香港",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.561968,
                  "lng" : 114.4294999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.1435,
                  "lng" : 113.8259001
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.3192011,
               "lng" : 114.1696121
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.561968,
                  "lng" : 114.4294999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.1435,
                  "lng" : 113.8259001
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJByjqov3-AzQR2pT0dDW0bUg",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "香港",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.5619469,
                  "lng" : 114.4294999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.1435,
                  "lng" : 113.8259001
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 22.3193039,
               "lng" : 114.1693611
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 22.5619469,
                  "lng" : 114.4294999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 22.1435,
                  "lng" : 113.8259001
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJD5gyo-3iAzQRfMnq27qzivA",
         "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want fixed? The addresses _are_ in chinese as I can see...
From geocoding api documentation: ***The geocoder does its best to provide a street address that is readable for both the user and locals. To achieve that goal, it returns street addresses in the local language, transliterated to a script readable by the user if necessary, observing the preferred language. All other addresses are returned in the preferred language. Address components are all returned in the same language, which is chosen from the first component.***

Comment: From the first address components , Only the HONG香 KONG港 is in chinese .

               "long_name" : "Tin Shui Wai",
               "short_name" : "Tin Shui Wai",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },

               "long_name" : "New Territories",
               "short_name" : "New Territories",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "香港",
               "short_name" : "HK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]